# Java: Why are enum fields not considered constant at compile time?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, constant-expression

I am attempting to use an enum to store ID values that I can use in a switch statement later. However despite the fact the `id` value is stored as `final byte` and that you cannot add new enum entries at runtime, the compiler seems unable to realise the values are constant and thus gives the error `constant expression required`. Enums, by definition, are data types for storing predefined constants
and yet it seems I cannot use them as such. Am I doing something unusual to warrant this strange behaviour or are Java enums not as robust as they perhaps should be?

```
public class Animal {
    enum AnimalClasses {
        MAMMAL((byte)0x00),
        FISH((byte)0x01),
        REPTILE((byte)0x02),
        AMPHIBIAN((byte)0x03),
        BIRD((byte)0x04);

        public final byte id;
        private AnimalClasses(byte id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public short animalID;

    public void updateAnimal() {
        //Animal ID contains class ID encoded within
        byte animalClassID = (byte) (animalID & 0xFF);

        switch (animalClassID) {
            case AnimalClasses.MAMMAL.id:   //ERROR: Constant expression required
                //Do mammal things
                break;
            case AnimalClasses.FISH.id:     //ERROR: Constant expression required
                //Do fish things
                break;
            //...
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those enum properties are treated like normal class properties, i.e. even though they are declared final they _could_ be changed at runtime (e.g. using reflection).

Comment: They are not compile-time constants, as enums are runtime objects which are instantiated and capable of being mutated. With reflection, you could change the values of those fields that are `final`. That said, you can switch on the enum constants themselves (`switch (someConst) { case AnimalClasses.MAMMAL: ... }`), which can be assisted by a method within the enum like `AnimalClasses#getByID(byte id)`.

Comment: Like many such 'why' questions, the answer is simply 'cuz'. The spec says so. Perhaps the question is best reformulated as: How do I do something like this - at that point, e.g. @Rogue's comment could be turned into an answer.

Comment: Note that an expression like `(byte) (animalID & 0xFF)` sends contradicting messages about you intention. Do you want a value between `0` and `255`, as `… & 0xFF` suggests, or do you want a value between `-128` and `127`, as produced by the type cast `(byte)…`? In the latter case, just using `byte animalClassID = (byte)animalID;` would be enough. Note that this value gets promoted to `int` anyway when using `switch (animalClassID) { … }`, so the cast is only necessary when there are actual upper bits to truncate. If `animalID` contains a value between zero and four anyway, you can just use it.

Comment: And if the `id` is always identical to the ordinal, as in your example, you can just use `Animal a = Animal.values()[(byte)animalID];`

Comment: Enums [are changeable at runtime](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue272-Hacking-Enums-Revisited.html) though it's a really, really bad idea to do. But it's possible, so they're not truly constant.